# Can I use extension methods on any class in Dart?

Tags: dart, extension-methods

I am trying to write an extension method for the Decimal class with:

```
void parse() {
  Decimal two = Decimal.two;
}

extension on Decimal {
  static Decimal get two => Decimal.fromInt(2);
}
```

However, Dart says that "The getter 'two' isn't defined for the class Decimal." Do extension methods only work on the Dart native classes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use  below line of code in your import :

```
import 'YourFileName.dart' show ExtensionName;
```

In your 'YourFileName.dart' it should be like :

```
extension  ExtensionName on Decimal {
  static Decimal get two => Decimal.fromInt(2);
}
```

Then use it as per your requirement.

Let me know if you are still stucking anywhere using **extensions** with **dart**.

Comment: This seems to only work if I call it with `ExtensionName.two`

Comment: You have to manually type in the imports? If that's the case, gonna skip them for now... Wastes more time that it saves.

Comment: Nope then just import your file.. and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is not use keyword `static` because these methods a related to `this`:

```
extension ExtensionName on Decimal {
  // `static` keyword removed
  Decimal get two => Decimal.fromInt(2);
  // `this` means the decimal to which this extension method is applied
  Decimal get square => this * this;     
}
```